# Views For Unread Gem For Public activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, public-activity, read-unread

I'm trying to implement a facebook like notification system in Rails using public activity and [gem unread](https://github.com/ledermann/unread).
I have installed the gem and created a public_activity.rb file in config/initializers. Code

```
PublicActivity::Activity.class_eval do
  acts_as_readable :on => :created_at
end
```

How do I create my views such that I can show the number of unread messages and also highlight these messages in my activities index.

My initial attempt at this looks like so

```
<%= PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_id: current_user.following_ids , owner_type: "User").unread_by(current_user).count %>
```

This gives me all notifications instead of just the unread ones. A
Any ideas on how I can modify this?

Comment: Looks like you need to write a code for your views that will show the number of unread messages and highlight these messages.

Comment: Please update the question with your initial attempt, the relatively big code snippets are unreadable in comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `created_at` is never empty. Just remove `acts_as_readable :on => :created_at` from your model. Default value is `updated_at`.